# Trying to write CSV file to Oracle databse table with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write aa table to an Oracle database using Python's pandas.

Here's is my code:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
import csv
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/admin/Desktop/customer.csv')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('SYSTEM/Mouni123$@localhost/orcl')
df = df.to_sql('cust', conn, 'if_exists=replace')
conn.close()
df
```

I get the following error:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that your code is actually trying to export to a SQLite database which is expected to fail if, in fact, the target is an Oracle database.

If I understand the [documentation for `dataframe.to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) correctly, it assumes an SQLite database as the target by default. So, in order to use Oracle as a database target, you'll have to make that explicit using SQLAlchemy as described in the documentation.